# For bounded sequences, does convergence of the Abel means imply that for the Cesàro means?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

See the title. This is true if the sequence is nonnegative; some Tauberian theorems which I was able to find give some more general sufficient conditions. I would like to know if this is true for arbitrary bounded sequences.

Recall that for a sequence $(a_n)$ with natural indices $n$, the Cesàro means are $\frac1{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_n$, and the Abel means are $(1-r)\sum\limits_n r^n a_n$.

Comment: @J.M.: you removed the set over which the sum is taken in the definition of the Cesaro means. Well, let it be, let us hope that the readers know this.

Comment: I'll restore it. I was going for consistency since it looked fine for you to omit the index terms in the Abel mean...

Comment: You are welcome to make it looking perfect))

Comment: In any event: I imagine Hardy's book on divergent series ought to have results on this. Have you checked that already?

Comment: Yes I did. I did not find this result and they don't seem to pay special attention to bounded sequences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. For the following modes of convergence 
you can  prove $(1)\Rightarrow (2)\Rightarrow (3)\Rightarrow (4)$.

$$\begin{eqnarray}
a_n &\to& a \qquad (1)\\ 
\sigma_n:={1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_j &\to& a \qquad (2)\\
(1-r)\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n r^n &\to& a\qquad (3)\\
(1-r)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_n r^n &\to& a\qquad (4)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

If $a_n$ is a *bounded* sequence then 
$(2)\Longleftrightarrow (3)$.
One direction is $(2)\Rightarrow (3)$ and the other follows
from [Littlewood's Tauberian theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_tauberian_theorem#Littlewood.27s_extension_of_Tauber.27s_theorem) ($(4)\Rightarrow (2)$) since $\sigma_{n+1}-\sigma_n$
is $O(1/n)$.

---

**Reference.** For further information and two  proofs of the "Abel to Cesàro" 
 theorem, see Chapter 1, sections 7, 11, and 12 of [*Tauberian Theory: A Century of Development*](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Tauberian_theory.html?id=Kh_nJe1ZWDoC) 
by Jacob Korevaar.

Comment: Looks very nice, I just want to check all details. Do you know a reference?

Comment: I'll try to find more precise references when I get home, and have access to my books.